# How to access elements of array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Below is the code snippet:

```
$resultArray = explode("\n",$cmd);
print_r($resultArray);
$tempArray = array();
foreach($resultArray as $key){
        $tempArray = explode(" ",$key);
         print_r($tempArray);
}
```

first print gives output:-

```
Array
(

 [0] => AA-BB-E3-1B-81-6A 10.10.10.2
 [1] => CC-DD-E3-1B-7E-5A 10.10.10.3
)
```

Second print gives output:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => AA-BB-E3-1B-81-6A
    [1] => 10.10.10.2
)
Array
(
    [0] => CC-DD-E3-1B-7E-5A
    [1] => 10.10.10.3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 
)
```

Assuming there will be many entries of mac addresses corresponding mac addresses, I want to store them in separate variables for further use.

Please help. I am new to PHP, learning on my own. Any help is appreciated.

eidt 1: Expected output should be two arrays, one each for mac address and Ip Address from which I would be able to loop through and query database for each mac address.

Comment: are you wanting to just get an array of all mac address into one array variable? If not, can you give an example of your expected result?

Comment: what do you actually need to do?

Comment: yes, I have edited the question with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure what you want to do, but from the little I understood is to separate the mac addresses:

```
$resultArray = explode("\n", $cmd);
print_r($resultArray);
$tempArray = array();
foreach($resultArray as $key){
    $dm = explode(" ", $key);
    $tempArray[] = $dm[0];
}
print_r($tempArray);
```

The result would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => AA-BB-E3-1B-81-6A
    [1] => CC-DD-E3-1B-7E-5A
     .
     .
     .
)
```

It would be much better if you put the expected result, in order to help you better.

Answer (score -1):

You forget [] for tempArray :

```
$resultArray = explode("\n",$cmd);
print_r($resultArray);
$tempArray = array();
foreach($resultArray as $key){
        $tempArray[] = explode(" ",$key);
         print_r($tempArray);
}
```